# pip not working through python shell

Tags: python, pip

I am quite new to python, and I'm trying to install pygame for a personal project, and the site recommends I use pip to install it. That's where I run into the problem.

When I enter

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

into the python shell, I get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It also highlights the 'pip' part of that.

The only thing I can think of is I don't have pip installed. But I am using python 3.6.2 and doesn't it already come with pip?

Am I stupid? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't enter that in the python console.

If you're in Windows, make sure you enter that in the Command Line (cmd).

Also, usually `pip install package_name` is enough, in which "package-name" is your "pygame". As said before, `-U` is to update an older version, so given those conditions, you don't need to put it there.

Hope it helps.

Pedro

PS: Also, `--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges. If it's what you want, go for `pip install package_name --user`, in which "package-name" is your "pygame".

Answer (score 0):

I've never run pip this way. pip is a standalone program and is normally run from the command line not using the python shell. So run

```
pip3 install pygame
```

the -U switch is only needed if you have an old copy of pygame installed already which you need to upgrade. I've never seen the --user switch and can't find it in the pip documentation but I presume it is an attempt to install a local copy of pygame. In which case, unless you run pip as root (via sudo -H) (administrator on windows) you should get a local copy anyway.

Comment: I've tried running that exactly, but I still get the same SyntaxError... Any other ideas for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use `cmd.exe`, not the python shell! if you really want to install through the python shell, for some strange reason, use `import pip; pip.main(['install', 'pygame'])`

Comment: which operating system are you using? If it is macos that might explain it - you'll need to use brew (I think)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the way used on Windows when both python2 and python3 installed such as `py -3 -m pip install package_name`. 
But on linux you don't need to do that. 
You can use `pip3 install package_name` directly. And -U is used to update an older version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using Linux. I'm using windows

Comment: If you don't have python2, pip install package_name is enough.